# Fractional Linear Trasformation Notation Question

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove: let $T$ be a fractional linear transformation. Then $T(|z| = 1)$ and
$T(|z| = 2)$ are concentric circles.

Can someone tell me what this notation is. Does $T(|z|=x)$ it mean the transform such that $T(|z|) = x$?

Comment: No, $T(|z|=1)$ means $T(\{z\in \Bbb{C} : |z| = 1\})$. In words: it is the image under $T$ of the points on the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks, that is a sufficient answer. So if you copy it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

No, $T(|z|=1)$ means $T(\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\})$. In words: it is the image under $T$ of the points on the unit circle.